# When $a, b > 0$ and $a = b$, how does $ab-a^2 = b^2 - a^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

This may be very rudimentary, but nontheless,

when $a, b > 0$ and $a = b$, how does $ab-a^2 = b^2 - a^2$?

I know that:
$a^2 = ab$, $a^2 = b^2$, and $b^2 = ab$

To give context, these are steps taken from the false proof for 1=2 (due to a step of dividing by 0 as part of the proof).

Comment: `I know that...` That's correct, and pretty much sums it up. Are you asking how does `0=0`?

Comment: I am asking how step #3: ab=b^2 and step #4: ab−a^2=b^2−a^2 in the false proof of 1=2 are a logically equivalent.

Comment: You didn't show the `false proof` so I can't comment on that. But you did say that `I know that: a^2 = ab` which implies $a b - a^2=0$. Then you did say `I know that: [...] a^2 = b^2` which implies $b^2 - a^2 = 0$. So you have just proved that $a b - a^2=0=b^2 - a^2$. I am not sure what you mean by `logically equivalent` - but you *did* prove that the two sides are equal (since they are both equal to $0$), which is all that was to be proved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a=b, so they can be substituted for each other freely:

b^2-a^2=b^2-a^2

bb-a^2=b^2-a^2

ab-a^2=b^2-a^2.

a and b are just two names for the same thing.

Comment: I don't understand your last step.

Comment: Oh no I do actually, thanks.

Comment: alright. cool. interesting fact. I figured out the proof in the opposite direction by starting with line 3 and ending up with line 1, and then wrote it backwards so it would look fancy. That's all people do for proofs sometimes. haha.